# CodeIgniter displays page with no css instead of 404

Tags: codeigniter, routes, uri

I am new to CodeIgniter and I have some issues with its routing config.

Everything works fine if I access a page as it should be

http://localhost/index.php/class/controller

But if I add some random arguments

http://localhost/index.php/class/controller/randomStuff

it displays the page without the CSS or the JS but I would like to display a 404 error page.

Here is my route.php file

```
$route['stats'] = 'main/account';
$route['/'] = 'index.php';
$route['/(:any)'] = 'main/disperr'; //Tried this to solve the problem but doesn't work (disperr simply returns show_404())
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';
$route['all'] = 'main';
$route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit : Thank you for your answers !
After routing the pages correctly I stil had the missing css issue.
As I'm using twig, I sent the base_url() as a parameter to my view and added it to the path to my CSS and JS. 
It works now.

Answer (score 0):

you may plese the following url

> http://localhost/class/index.php/main

after index.php you need to give your name of the controller(not folder name controller)

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow some rules from documentation page.
Routes you found after CodeIgniter installation have to be at the beginning in order you found those.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main';//Main class need to have index() method for this works
$route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

You have to take care of precedence because rules will be read in order those are defined in file.

```
$route['all'] = 'main';
$route['stats'] = 'main/account';
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/disperr'; //Tried this to solve the problem but doesn't work (disperr simply returns show_404())
```

If you have `(:any)` wildcard placeholder it has to be at the end of file because you have to check all specific routes not to pass (:any) rule, because that rule is valid for any route (as name suggest). Slash to index route is not needed because slash is default controller and it is already defined. Routing to `index.php` is not valid and you are suppose to route just to `'controller_name/method_name/param1'` or similar pattern. No need for slashes at the beginning, as you see I removed those. Maybe removing slashes from the beginning of made routes will solve your CSS issue, but you need to follow other documentation rules I exposed here. Read full page [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).